# img move to bottom after float right

Tags: css

`img` moved to bottom after `float:right;`

see to footer: http://qass.im/thestandard/

this footer code:

```
footer{
display:block;
margin:0 auto;
margin-bottom:50px;
width:800px;
height:100%;
clear:both;
}

.footer-content{
padding:80px;
padding-top:0;
padding-bottom:0;
}

footer p{
line-height: 1.714285714;
font-size:14px;
color:#555;
}

footer p a{
color:#555;
border-bottom:1px dotted #555;
}

.social-icon{
font-size:0;
float:right;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Do it this way.

**The Code Changes:**

```
<div class="footer-content">

<div class="social-icon">
<a target="_blank" href="#"><img src="http://qass.im/thestandard/wp-content/themes/thestandard/images/twitter-footer.png"></a>
<a target="_blank" href="#"><img src="http://qass.im/thestandard/wp-content/themes/thestandard/images/facebook-footer.png"></a>
<a target="_blank" href="#"><img src="http://qass.im/thestandard/wp-content/themes/thestandard/images/google-footer.png"></a>
</div>

<p>
Powered by <a target="_blank" href="http://wordpress.org">WordPress</a> ©2013 The Standard, The Standard theme by <a target="_blank" href="http://qass.im/thestandard">Qassim.Dev</a>
</p>

</div>
```

This will make your image not to jump to the bottom.

Answer (score 1):

They are rendered under the paragraph. As a `p` tag is block-level - so it occupies the full width.

What you can do:

**variant 1:** make `.footer-content p {float: left;}`

**variant 2:** change the order in your html. Make the div with a class of `social-icon` go *before* the paragraph.

Answer (score 1):

delete the .social-icon's float
and use display:inline; for .social-icon and footer p

Comment: I quite disagree that this is needed. In your variant - the social icons will stick to the text. Whereas by design we can assume they should always be stuck to the right. What will happen if we make the text larger/smaller?

Answer (score 0):

i have visited your page it isnt on the bottom because of `float:right;` (use a debugger - like firebug -  and disable `float:right;` to check), its there because of the fact that it is a `block` element under another `block` element use `display:inline-block;` in your `.social-icon` and `footer p` css.

in conclusion

```
footer p{
    display:inline-block;
}

.social-icon{
    display:inline-block;
    font-size:0;
    float:right;
}
```

and BOOM! i did this in firebug on your site and it worked fine.